# How to close eletrical circuit (closet lighting on opening the door)

Tags: led, switches

I bought these (magnetic?) switches from China that open and close the circuit when they touch each other or are close.

[image: close door switch]

My problem is that they work in the current setup in the picture in the opposite. Right now the lights would be on when the door is opened.

I guess I need to wire led to batter directly, but between then I need some kind of component that blocks the circuit when the switch is touching each other.

Am I missing something, is there any other way to build what I want to?
I was trying all sort of keywords but I don't know what component I need.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having so much trouble with your wording. Is it that the switches are "closed" when near each other, or "open" when near each other? And do you want the light to go ON when near each other? Or OFF when near each other? I can't tell what you actually have and what you actually want to have and how they are different from each other. I'm sorry. Also, what kind of light is to be controlled?

Comment: I'm sorry for my English. I want to control 3 bright little LEDs with a 9V battery. I want the light to be ON when they DON'T touch each other. Right now the light is ON when they are close, meaning exactly the opposite what I'm planning to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn’t the switch part have 3 terminals: common and “no” & “nc” ie normally open & normally closed.

So once the switch is fitted with the door closed the magnet holds the contacts open ie off and when the door is open the contacts are closed ie on.

Comment: It has only NC and COM. Meaning when the two plastic things in the picture touch each other, it is opened. But for my project, it does exactly the opposite thing. It would light up when I close the cabinet door.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have bought a contact type switch - you need a "push to open" type switch : when the plunger or lever is pushed it opens ie turns "off" the circuit.

Comment: I have realized that. But can't I make use of the same switch so if it is ON, it gives a signal to stop the circuit. I would power the LEDs from the same source. Basically is there some sort of component that I can use if it is "powered on", it will cut the electrcity from flowing to the LED.

Comment: yes, use a relay, but realise that the relay coil will draw power in the "off" position...

Comment: I think then the only good way would do it mechanically, meaning they make contact only when the door is opened. it's a bit difficult but it can be done. Or just buy new ones that are normally closed.

Comment: which is what I suggested an hour ago "you need a "push to open" type switch : when the plunger or lever is pushed it opens ie turns "off" the circuit."

Comment: Relax, I marked your answer as correct :)
I was just hoping there is a component that can be used, but as you said relay will use electricity hence it's not a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: you may be able to find a component equivalent circuit but it still uses energy... source the correct type of switch or even make one with a spring and pair of contacts : it's only low volts and current

Comment: I'm actually investigating things called "latch relay" and I found some Chinese ones that are very small and use allegedly 0.001mA when on standby. I'm not sure if understand everything correctly, but thank you for guiding me the right path.